# Show/Hide dependent attribute field on toggle attribute field of product add/edit admin form into Magenot 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, uicomponent, adminform, dependent-fields

As per the requirement, I have created 2 product attribute into magento 2 admin. First attribute is toggle(Yes/No) attribute and Second is Text attribute which is dependent on First attribute. Now I have to Show/Hide Text attribute based on Toggle attribute value into product admin form.